# Python manage.py collectstatic TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Tags: django, typeerror

I'm working with Django version 2.2 . When I run the command 
`python manage.py collectstatic`

I get the following log on bash terminal.

```
You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings:

    /home/djapp/poorface/staticfiles

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/amit/.virtualenvs/hola/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/amit/.virtualenvs/hola/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/amit/.virtualenvs/hola/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/amit/.virtualenvs/hola/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/amit/.virtualenvs/hola/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 188, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
  File "/home/amit/.virtualenvs/hola/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 114, in collect
    handler(path, prefixed_path, storage)
  File "/home/amit/.virtualenvs/hola/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 353, in copy_file
    self.storage.save(prefixed_path, source_file)
  File "/home/amit/.virtualenvs/hola/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 49, in save
    return self._save(name, content)
  File "/home/amit/.virtualenvs/hola/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 288, in _save
    os.chmod(full_path, self.file_permissions_mode)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

I changed the permissions of the staticfiles to -rwxrwxrwx . Then also there is no change in output.

manage.py looks like

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Poorface.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: What's the shell say about the permissions when you run `ls -al /home`? It may be related to something platform specific... e.g. OSX has extended permissions attributes. The paths `/home/djapp` and `/home/amit` look a little bit sketchy... Are you sure you want to emit the statics to a different "home" directory?

Comment: ls -al /home
drwxr-xr-x  8 amit      amit      4096 Mar 13 15:29 amit
drwxr-xr-x  5 djapp     djapp     4096 Mar 13 17:23 djapp

Comment: If it works then there is no problem in emitting the statics to different "home" directory.

Comment: You might try running with the `--dry-run` flag to so you can see what file paths are being referred to. You can then check the permissions on the given folders. You might also try setting STATIC_ROOT to a location can be very certain is accessible... e.g. `/tmp` at the root of the filesystem.

Comment: `--dry-run` flag helped me to sort out the problem. But still, I didn't get why this error happened. I'm passing the `yes` argument which is one of the argument to be passed & permissions to the files and folders are also fine.

Comment: So was the problem resolved when you changed the STATIC_ROOT? Still seems likely related to ownership and permissions somewhere along the `/home/djapp/poorface/staticfiles` tree.

Comment: I didn't change anything in STATIC_ROOT just ran the `python manage.py collectstatic` with `--dry-run` . It resolved the main issue that I was facing.

Comment: Are you sure that actually resolved the problem? `--dry-run` collects the statics and determines the destinations as usually, but it doesn't actually perform the filesystem operations. So the statics aren't copied so the TypeError in your question won't be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack - not a proper fix!

I had this problem on both OSX and Ubuntu.  Seems that certain packages end up with file permission as string, whereas most are integer.

I hacked django to fix this and identified the package causing the problem - django-filebrowser - probably best not to hack django but if desperate here is the change in core/files/storage.py line 289::

```
    if self.file_permissions_mode is not None:

        if type(self.file_permissions_mode) == type("duck"):
              print(full_path, self.file_permissions_mode, type(self.file_permissions_mode))
              self.file_permissions_mode = int(self.file_permissions_mode)
        os.chmod(full_path, self.file_permissions_mode)
```

This reported::

```
  /home/django/teamup/shared_static/filebrowser/css/filebrowser.css 0644 <class 'str'>
```

I tried changing the file permissions for filebrowser in place in the virtualenv and rerunning but this did not fix the problem so I've gone with the hack.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this question is old but I run into this now again and found the error-source and the proper fix after some tufts of grey hair, tampering all sorts of of file-access-rights and one simple debug-run of "manage.py collectstatic":

In the olden days or maybe in some different context (can't remember how this crept in to my project-dev-settings - in my production setting it was correct) it is/was fine to set the "FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS" in the settings.py like this:

```
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = "0644"
```

According to the docs at least since [Django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#file-upload-permissions) the **correct setting** is:

```
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0o644
```

after I knew the reason an the solution I also found a few hints that's "now with python 3 … octals … etc. etc." but no connection to this enervating vague error message:

```
…  os.chmod(full_path, self.file_permissions_mode)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

after I used a command `python manage.py collectstatic` which "allways™" (I know) worked.

So I hope you don't get this much grey hair over some slightly stale projects like me!